# Should the p in p-value (probability value) use the math environment or \emph{}?

Tags: emphasis

I usually use `$p$-value` but I was wondering if `\emph{p}-value` is the recommended way to typeset terms with a one or more italicized character?

(Edit: Similar cases include *t*-test, *t*-statistic and *t*-distribution where the italicized character may also be used in a math expression; and *n*-type, *p*-type and *k*-correction where the italicized character is an abbreviation)

Comment: Probably better asked elsewhere, as it is really off-topic here. We can say how to do either, but which is preferable is not our concern. That said, I expect somebody will know or, if not that, somebody will have an opinion, at least. Do you plan to use `$\text{\emph{p}}$`, for example, in a maths context? Do you want the `p` to be typeset upright if the surrounding text is in italics? I would think that, even if text mode is preferable, `\emph{}` would not be the way to do it. (See, I don't know - but I have an uninformed opinion.)

Comment: Probably there won't be a unique answer, but I prefer $p$--value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Absolutely definitely not emph*

As `\emph` is for doing ↑↑↑↑ using (some) font change for emphasis. It may use an italic font, or it may use upright (if the current font is italic) or it may use bold or red (if the document class designer so chooses).

So the choices are `\textit` for text italic or `$` for math. I think math is more appropriate and makes the p or t match the font used if those letters are used in an expression $t$-test .... $t=\frac{Z}{s}$ .... or whatever.

Comment: There is a kerning issue if you use something like $V$-mode or $T$-mode. Is there a good way around this or does this have to be adjusted manually?

Comment: @gdkrmr manual, probably would need same for `\mathit{T}-mode` as well

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! What look fine is \textit{V-}mode but is not probably not the intended use, even \textit{V}-mode doesn't look pretty. Also (in my case) it uses a different font than math mode.

Comment: @gdkrmr yes of course textit{V} will use a different font than $V$ that is the point of this question, asking which to use.